# Mimic Tabs in Textile and HTML (in Ruby)?

Tags: html, ruby, tabs, textile

How do you mimic tabs in HTML?  Specifically, I would like to be able to use tabs to align things in a textile document, and convert those to "non-breaking spaces" and whatnot in HTML, using RedCloth in Ruby.  Is this possible?  Is there an alternative working method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, textile documents *do* have the easy-table "markdown"...

```
|a|simple|table|row|
|And|Another|table|row|
```